# Filter pre_get_posts does not modify Mine/All/Pending

Tags: filters, wp-admin, pre-get-posts

Maybe I need to use a different filter, but I am using the pre_get_posts filter to filter out posts on a custom post list view.  It works for the main table, but the quicklinks to (All) (Published) (Pending) etc still show the full counts, not the modified query counts.

Any thoghts on how to change that?